# How I can display 2 Dimensional JSON Data to my React Native FlatList

Tags: json, react-native, google-sheets

I have want to display Google Spreadsheet data into my React native FlatList view. I added Data to my SpreadSheet and via Script I fetch those data into JSON format but it gives me a 2 Dimensional JSON Data , And this is the difficult part for me. I was not able to fetch the 2 Dimensional JSON data to my react-native flat list. I also tried with offline

**This is My JSON Data:**
`{"user":[{"name":"Arbaz","name2":"Salim"},{"name":"Imtiyaz","name2":"Kudekar"},{"name":"Shaikh ","name2":"Arbaz"}]}`

So how I can display this data to my Flat-list?

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ListView,Image,FlatList,List,ListItem } from 'react-native';
import { Header,Left,Body,Right,Title } from 'native-base';

import data from './sales.json';
const basketIcon = require('./123.png');


export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
      <Header>
          <Left/>
          <Body>
            <Title>Header</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
        <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
        <Image source={basketIcon} style={styles.icon} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.info}>
        <Text style={styles.items}>{item.items} Items</Text>
        <Text style={styles.address}>{item.address}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.total}>
        <Text style={styles.date}>{item.date}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.price}>${item.total}</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
        }
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
   </View>
    )
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 mainContainer: {
 flex: 1,
 backgroundColor: '#fff',
 },
 title: {
 backgroundColor: '#0f1b29',
 color: '#fff',
 fontSize: 18,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 padding: 10,
 paddingTop: 40,
 textAlign: 'center',
 },
 row: {
 borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
 borderBottomWidth: 1,
 flexDirection: 'row',
 marginLeft: 10,
 marginRight: 10,
 paddingTop: 20,
 paddingBottom: 20,
 },
 iconContainer: {
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#feb401',
 borderColor: '#feaf12',
 borderRadius: 25,
 borderWidth: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 height: 50,
 width: 50,
 },
 icon: {
 tintColor: '#fff',
 height: 22,
 width: 22,
 },
 info: {
 flex: 1,
 paddingLeft: 25,
 paddingRight: 25,
 },
 items: {
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: 16,
 marginBottom: 5,
 },
 address: {
 color: '#ccc',
 fontSize: 14,
 },
 total: {
 width: 80,
 },
 date: {
 fontSize: 12,
 marginBottom: 5,
 },
 price: {
 color: '#1cad61',
 fontSize: 25,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 },

 });
```

I tried with Parse JSON Method also but it didn't work for me It show only first row with filled data

Answer (score 0):

If you have extracted data and put that in a variable, suppose x, then: 
const x = data;

```
<FlatList
        data={x.user}
 ....
 />
```

And inside renderItem use item.name or item.name2 to get the value. I don't think there is anything wrong with the JSON you are receiving!

Comment: Still this is also not work for me,  @JustBeginner  Please can you explain me what do you mean by Extracted data